# LP Feasible Region

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

Hello guys I have a question to Linear Programming.

Draw the feasible region for the following linear program:

*min*

```
 sx + ty
```

*st.*

```
 2x +  y <= 7
-6x + 5y >= -5
 -x + 4y <= 18
       y <= 4
```

(The problem should not be changed to a feasibilty problem, i.e., s=t=0 is not allowed.)

So what I did so far I calculated the extremepoints they are:

1. (0,4)
2. (1.5, 4)
3. (2.5, 2)
4. (0.83, 0)
5. (0, 0)

[image: Feasible region]
Give appropitate values for s and t that the linear program has

1. exactly one solution

   I understand if I have one solution when I chose s = t = 1
2. multiple optimal solutions, where each one is bounded (i.e. none of its components has arbitrarily large magnitude).

   ?
3. multiple optimal solutions, unbounded

   my guess was s = 1 and t = 0, these are the points (0, 4) and (0, 0)
   and the whole line between them and there are infinite many points on 
   that line
4. no optimal solution

   ?

Comment: Glad I stumbled upon this question. Definitely saved me some time preparing the final exercise sheet for Algorithmics tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the feasible region should extend further to the bottom left beyond the x and y axes, since you do not have a constraint in the form x>0 or y>0.

1) see 4), probably better is s=t=-1

2) e.g., s=-2, t=-1, then each point between 2. and 3. has the same minimum value. So the solution is bounded by the points 2. and 3. Also s=1 ant t=0 as mentioned by you is a bounded solution.

3) e.g., s=1, t=-4, then each point on the function -x + 4y = 18 (for y <= 4) is part of the minimum

4) I am not sure about this one but probably s=t=1, then the minimum is reached when x=y = - \infinity thus there is no minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I thought that the non-negative constraint is active every time, but so it makes more sense.

Comment: I did go through it in detail again and you are absolutely right, thank you very much. For me, it was unintuitive that we have a negative feasible region for real-world problems. Also for 4) it's the only possible reasoning.